# Erro: Another git process seems to be running in this repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

Tenho um repositório com diversos arquivos, inclusive *html, javascript, css* entre outros, e hoje tive este erro, ja pesquisei bastante mais nenhuma solucao ate agora surtiu efeito.

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
>   an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to continue.

Comment: Se não der certo apaga o lock e rebuta a maquina e tenta novamente deve soltar. Não sei explicar porque mas a causa é essa.

Comment: @Marcelo, se alguma das resposta lhe ajudou a entender o problema não esqueça de marca-la como certa, assim ajuda as outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida a encontrar a resposta mais facilmente.

Comment: @Marcelo, não entendo o porque nos últimos minutos tirou a resposta como correta, só para não receber a recompensa? você sabe que depois que você coloca uma recompensa numa pesquisa, mesmo que você não dê para ninguém como resposta correta ela não volta pra você né?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta ver se existe um processo git em execução no windows task manager. Se houver, mata o processo e apaga o index.lock na pasta .git

Normalmente resolve o problema ;)

Answer (score 18):

Este erro acontece pois dentro do diretório `.git` existe um arquivo chamado `index.lock`, após excluir este arquivo você conseguirá executar comandos git.

**Mas afinal, o que é o index.lock?**

O arquivo index.lock é criado toda vez que ocorra alguma alteração no arquivo index original.
Para garantir que o arquivo original não acabe corrompido, o git cria o index.lock com todas as novas informações, salva e renomeia-o para index, substituindo então o original.

> O arquivo index por sua vez, é um arquivo binário (geralmente mantido
>   em .git / index) contendo uma lista ordenada de todos os caminhos dos
>   arquivos que estão sendo versionados pelo git, cada um com permissões
>   e o SHA1 do blob deste arquivo.

Ou seja, todos os arquivos que estão sendo monitorados pelo git são listados no index juntamente com seu caminho, as permissões (leitura,escrita,executável) e o hash SHA1 dele.

Você consgue ver o conteúdo do arquivo index com o comando `git ls-files`.
Para exibir o conteúdo do index para todos os arquivos versionados execute:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 d1bed128fa83b3ed094d8387f4b8f19c019e2ae8 0       crud/.gitignore
100644 62dff0d03aeddb3cfc3e10ded315193fcf00f4c4 0       crud/app.js
100644 86091205bdb895f94d904c1c1a00457e2a3355f0 0       crud/bin/www
100644 afa3b3b360b58def97f483a7163032abba849fc9 0       crud/db.js
100644 311524c74e19968b8a580c19ed663b4e2e96a34e 0       crud/package-lock.json
100644 da91bb97990abbf27edbd2c93046054e458d0e4e 0       crud/package.json
100644 9453385b9916ce9bc5e88d2f5d8cd8a554223590 0       crud/public/stylesheets/style.css
```

A primeira coluna com os números `100644` representa as permições, a segunda coluna é o hash SAH1, a terceira é o stage number (este é utilizado para representar os conflitos de merge) e a quarta coluna é o caminho do seu arquivo.
Para obter mais detalhes sobre o que comentei acima de uma olhada [neste artigo](https://mincong-h.github.io/2018/04/28/git-index/#1-understand-index-via-git-ls-files) e no eBook [Git Community Book](https://shafiul.github.io//gitbook/7_the_git_index.html).

Agora que já entendemos o que são e para que servem os arquivo index e index.lock, acredito que fica fácil perceber que sempre que fizermos um commit, merge, tentarmos resolver um problema de conflict ou qualquer outro comando que o git precise recriar o index ele vai gerar este arquivo index.lock e até que este comando seja finalizado ele não vai salvar e substituir o arquivo index original, por este motivo o git não deixa executar outro comando enquanto o index.lock exista, pois ele entende que exista outro comando rodando naquele momento.

Answer (score 15):

Olá tive esse problema tbm usei esse comando e resolveu:

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

Espero que ajude quem tiver esse problema também!

Comment: Sua resposta é basicamente a mesma do Sandro Silva, porém a do Sandro Silva tem a preocupação de garantir que não haja mais algum processo git rodando (evitando alguma eventual corrupção do repositório). Também é extremamente semelhante à resposta aceita, porém sem a explicação nela contida da causa

Answer (score 8):

Você precisa tentar excluir o `index.lock` arquivo no seu `.git` diretório.

Esse problema ocorre sempre que você executa dois comandos git simultaneamente, talvez um do prompt de comando e um do IDE.

Comment: Não é um 'bug não tratado': está funcionando como deveria. Como você implementaria isso de outra forma?

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário @jsbueno, sim na realidade se ele adicionam o lock e uma mensagem está tratado, apenas removi o **me parece ...".